# What happens when i do : actualBranch merge into Master and actualBranch merge from Master git

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket

So I'm new to git and I'm working on a project and i have my own branch on git called actualBranch, and the other team member is working on master. I want to have the changes that he has made on my branch. Which one should I use if I am working on my branch to get the changes, merge into master or merge from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge from master, for example:

```
git checkout actualBranch
git pull
git merge master
```

or you can do rebase instead merge:

```
git rebase master
```

PS. Rebase should be made only for non-shared branch, so you can rebase you branch onto master, but not master onto your branch.

Comment: with this I will have all the changes on my branch and the master won't be affected?

Comment: master not affected. Changes go to currently checkout branch